# Visual Studio 2022 how to turn off the new Git experience

Tags: settings, visual-studio-2022

Looks like the option to turn off the new Git experience is gone from VS2022. And there is still no way to link in a DevOps work item like you could in the Team Explorer.

Has anyone found the off switch in VS022 for this "experience"?

Comment: What do you mean with "cannot link an item like in the old experience"? `#wi-id` in your commit comment does the trick... If you start the work from the web experience from the work item form, the branch will be auto-associated with the workitem. What problem does the old experience solve that the new one won't or that can't easily be solved with a small change in your way of working?

Comment: Side Note: When I first starting using VS2019 I didn't like the new Git experience as much (probably because I wasn't used to it), but by day 3 I was a convert. I think now the only thing I miss is the forward and back buttons in the commit details window. (Since commit details, compare commits, and changes are all separate windows now the forward and back buttons aren't really needed anymore, but sometimes when I view a few different commits I wish to go back and look at the last one I viewed.)

Comment: Just use git from the command line and you will never be affected by problems like this

Comment: Command line? Well there's a real step backwards in terms of UX. Re linking work items, rather than typing in a #item number the Team version has a pane linked to the project that lets you add work items from a list. Very useful but now gone in favour of the new "experience". A classic example of "fixing" something that wasn't broke and didn't fixing.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, if something is preventing me updating to VS2022, it's "new git experience"

Comment: If you start the work from the work item on the web ui, Azure DevOps will automatically create a branch for you and associate the work item.

Answer (score 20):

According to [Git for Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#how-to-use-the-full-team-explorer-experience-in-visual-studio),

"The new Git experience is the default version control system in Visual Studio 2019 from version 16.8 onwards. However, if you want to turn it off, you can. Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and then toggle the New Git user experience checkbox, which will switch you back to Team Explorer for Git."

According to [Git for Visual Studio 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022),

For Visual Studio 2022, the  new Git Experience is the *only* Git experience. Unfortunately, there is no way to revert back to the old Git experience.

Comment: The new Git experience is not intuitive not gives a good UX at all!

Comment: Quite disappointed that the old Git experience is removed from VS 22. With the new one they've taken one step forward and two steps back...

You now need to jump between two tabs just to do a simple commit and push. You also need to find a place for the new gigantic tab for the branch manager among your open files. Too much detail on the tabs where the old version abstracted details to a tidy compact UI. Not sure what took over the team who maintain the Git Experience but it feels like there wasn't sufficient beta testing involved.

Comment: There is a top level menu item for push as well as a keyboard shortcut and a window. What more do you want ;). I can tell the team who built the Team Explorer's git experience took on the new, much more powerful and easier to extend new git experience. Still the same developer lead.

Comment: It was beta tested for over a year. Many people like it. And other people just kept refusing to turn it on and provide feedback I assume.

Comment: It's not just about being too conservative. The old version I installed and simply started using straight away. With the new version, I even struggled to find how to check the branch history. Sure thing, it's just a matter of one-day usage but, as a matter of fact, the UX became worse, so, as a user of the product, I question the need for this "new experience"

Comment: It's classic Microsoft: change for change's sake, not to make the experience better. I tried new experience in 2019 and reverted back after a month of stumbling around in the new experience. I hoped my turning it off would be added with other clear analytics that the new experience was not better.  Guess not.

Comment: he is asking for vs 2022 version

Answer (score 4):

Caleb F. answered it in full, but for newer versions of VS 2022, the feature is called "Enable line-staging support", in the same "Preview Features" menu.

Comment: Okay it's no longer a "preview feature".  Where is it now?

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2019
for using old git user experience
user following step:

Go to Tools > Options > Environment >
review Features

[image]

Comment: he is asking for vs 2022